# Generate CSV file with results in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I need to generate CSV file with the stored procedure out put.
           Ex: 
           Select * From Table1

I want to generate a CSV file with the data which coming from select statement.

How can I achieve this in SQL Server?

Comment: Integration services provides a way to append results to a flat file

Comment: How to do that in Integration services?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a guide to take the results of a query and append them to a flat file destination using SSIS: http://knowlton-group.com/using-ssis-to-export-data-to-flat-files/

Answer (score 0):

That depends, if you are running the query using [`SQLCMD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) command line utility then you can use the `-o output_file` switch and specify a `*.csv` file as output destination.

Comment: What I want is I want to schedule the SQL JOB within in sql server to generate the CSV.